# How to send Twitter Fabric Session from Activity to Another Activity?

Tags: java, android, twitter-fabric

I want to send twitter session from activity to another activity.I have searched([How to pass an object from one activity to another on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736389/how-to-pass-object-from-one-activity-to-another-in-android#comment6849790_2736612)) but there is something wrong serializable TwitterSession. The scenario is when a user login successfully this session information goes to the MainActivity. Here is my code.
What is my wrong ?

TwitterSessionObject.java

```
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterSession;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class TwitterSessionObject implements Serializable {

    private TwitterSession session;

    public TwitterSessionObject(TwitterSession twitterSession){

        this.session = twitterSession;
    }    
    public TwitterSession getTwitterSession() {
        return session;
    }
    public void setSession(TwitterSession session) {
        this.session = session;
    }
}
```

Login.java

```
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        TwitterAuthConfig authConfig = new TwitterAuthConfig(TWITTER_KEY, TWITTER_SECRET);
        Fabric.with(this, new Twitter(authConfig));
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        loginButton = (TwitterLoginButton) findViewById(R.id.twitter_login_button);
        loginButton.setCallback(new Callback<TwitterSession>() {
            @Override
            public void success(Result<TwitterSession> result) {
                // Do something with result, which provides a TwitterSession for making API calls

                TwitterSession session = Twitter.getSessionManager().getActiveSession();
                TwitterAuthToken authToken = session.getAuthToken();
                String token = authToken.token;
                String secret = authToken.secret;

                TwitterSessionObject sessionObject = new TwitterSessionObject(session);

                Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, MainActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("Session", sessionObject);
                startActivity(intent);       
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
                // Do something on failure
            }
        });
    }
```

MainActivity.java

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        TwitterSessionObject session = (TwitterSessionObject)intent.getSerializableExtra("Session");          
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't pass it like that. `TwitterSession` isn't serializable so you can't make it a member of a serializable class.

Since TwitterSession is singleton, you can simply call the following method from your MainActivity

```
TwitterSession session = Twitter.getSessionManager().getActiveSession();
```

So your activity code would look like

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        TwitterSession session = Twitter.getSessionManager().getActiveSession();

}
```

Comment: ohh I'm so carelessness. Hours unsleepy. Thanks Man!

Answer (score 0):

in your MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private TwitterLoginButton loginButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    Boolean restoredText = prefs.getBoolean("loginStatus", false);
    if (restoredText == true) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, YourTwitterClass.class));
        finish(); // destroy login so user can't come back with back button
    }

    loginButton = (TwitterLoginButton) findViewById(R.id.twitter_login_button);
    loginButton.setCallback(new Callback<TwitterSession>() {
        @Override
        public void success(Result<TwitterSession> result) {

        startActivity(new Intent(this, YourTwitterClass.class));

        }

        @Override
        public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
        //do something
        }
    });
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    loginButton.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```